# EditText applied style weird behavior

Tags: android

I create an EditText Style :

```
 <style name="EditModeTextEdit">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/edittext_textcolor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edittext_textsize</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/textedit_border</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/form_margin</item>
 </style>
```

When I apply it with XML it looks fine :

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/my_acc_edit_tel_et"
  style="@style/EditModeTextEdit"
  android:singleLine="true"
  custom:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
/>
```

When I do the same in code, I get odd visual looks. Depending on which constructor I use.

Shows a regular edittext component

```
EditText et = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(mCtx, R.style.EditModeTextEdit));
```

Shows the styled component, but edittext cannot be interacted with(keyboard doesn't show up)

```
EditText et = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(mCtx, R.style.EditModeTextEdit), 0, null);
```

I am currently forced to manually set each element with the EditText set methods :

```
protected EditText createEditText(String defaultText, String uiTag)
{
        GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = createDefaultGridParams();
        lp.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        lp.width = 250;


        EditText et = new EditText(mCtx);
        et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.edittext_textcolor));
        et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textedit_border);
        et.setTag(uiTag);
        et.setText(defaultText);
        et.setSingleLine(true);
        et.setLayoutParams(lp);

     return et;
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go other way. You can create a template layout xml file with the style assigned, for example in `res/layout` create `ev_template.xml` as with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/my_acc_edit_tel_et"
  style="@style/EditModeTextEdit"
  android:singleLine="true"
  custom:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"/>
```

Then inflate this to your new EditText:

```
EditText et = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.ev_template, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
```

`attrs` contain all attrs and  `defStyle` contain all attr values.you put 0 and null in them .so  you can get no attr.